# Best date-format to use and sort with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a large Excel file which I will be reading into Pandas, for analysis. One of the columns contains dates. Since I am just beginning this project, I have the luxury of using whichever date-format works best. The problem is, I can't figure out which date-format to use and how to properly sort by date.

One potential issue is that some dates will be Year only, some will be Year-Month and some will be Year-Month-Day.

```
1997
1999
1997
1997-03
1997-10-31
2000-11
```

I'd like to be able to use Pandas to sort, by date, and end up with:

```
2000-11
1999
1997-10-31
1997-03
1997
1997
```

If it is easier that Year-only come first, then Year-Month, then Year-Month-Day, then the following is fine as well; as long as all the Year-only dates are grouped together.

```
2000-11
1999
1997
1997
1997-10-03
1997-03
```

I've tried converting them to a datetime object by using `pd.to_datetime` but am getting lost figuring out if I then need to convert those back to a string (in order to print them out).

I believe there is a much easier way to do this, especially since I can create the date-format however I like.

What is the best date-format to use, and what is the best way to sort by date (for this scenario)?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert a datetime back to a string just for printing it.

Comment: I was converting them to strings in order to avoid printing the index by using `(index=False)`, I haven't figured out how to otherwise; but, that's getting off-topic and printing or not printing the index isn't a big concern to me right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who happens to find themselves in this situation, @Haleemur Ali was on the right track; i.e. converting YYYY and YYYY/MM dates to YYYY/MM/DD dates.

Since I did not want to replace a date like `1991` with an arbitrary date of `1991-01-01`, the solution was to:

Explicitly convert dates to strings using `.astype('str')`; although these apparently were already strings, not doing this resulted in undesired dates in the next step.

Create a temporary column of dates, using the existing dates, and convert those using `pd.to.datetime`.

`sort_values` using the temporary column of dates. *This preserves the format of the original `Date` column.* Afterwards, the temporary date column can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting you describe is simply lexical sorting. So, you could keep the column as a string type & the sort to behave as expected.

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datecol': ['1997', '1999', '1997-03', '1997-10-31', '2000-11']})

df.datecol.sort_values(ascending=False)
# prints:
4       2000-11
1          1999
3    1997-10-31
2       1997-03
0          1997
Name: datecol, dtype: object
```

However, things are not as straightforward.

Consider how `1997` is less than `1997-10-31`.

This can only happen if `1997` represents a date value between `1997-01-01` and `1997-10-30` inclusive. But, you also expect `1997` to be ordered before `1997-03`. That implies `1997` is some value between `1997-01-01` and `1997-02-28`.

What would you expect if there was a value `1997-01`. Would that be ordered before or after `1997`, or would the two values be considered equivalent and also equivalent to `1997-01-01`.

Another option is to convert all partial dates to a complete date, by assigning month and day values if needed through some rule. Based on the sorting example you provided, a reasonable rule would be to set the day value to the first of the month if missing, and set the month value to january if missing.

This behaviour is default for the function `pd.to_datetime`

```
df['date_conv'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datecol)
df.sort_values('date_conv', ascending=False)
df
# outputs:
      datecol  date_conv
4     2000-11 2000-11-01
1        1999 1999-01-01
3  1997-10-31 1997-10-31
2     1997-03 1997-03-01
0        1997 1997-01-01
```

as you can see, the expected ordering is preserved

Comment: Thank you, Haleemur. Unfortunately, converting partial dates to arbitrary dates isn't an option. It really doesn't matter if Year-only dates come before or after Year-Month and Year-Month-Day dates (just that they're grouped together). I've updated my post to help clear this up.